# How to save a file into a directory in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I invoke "jupyter notebook" under:

```
 [abigail@localhost anaconda3]$ jupyter notebook
```

By default, it saves to the directory of anaconda3/ with an extension of "ipynb" when I click "File" => "Save".

How to save it to a directory under anaconda3/, instead of the default location? There is not a "save as" command in notebook?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can save a notebook to a location of your choice by using the "File" -> "Download as" -> "Notebook (.ipynb)" option from the menu.

Alternatively you can start your notebook server from a different directory and it will save all notebooks to that directory.

A third option is to navigate to the directory you want the notebook to be saved to in the tree view "http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree" prior to creating the notebook.

Comment: Just cd'ing to the directory I want and running `jupyter notebook` from there is simple and works grea--thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 8):

**There are two methods:**
1.You can use the magic command %notebook to save as ipynb

```
  %notebook "directory/to/file/filename.ipynb"
```

2.You can use the magic command %%writefile to save as py file

```
  %%writefile "directory/to/file/filename.py"
```

In the second method, you should put this command at the top of the cell, otherwise it will throw an error.

Comment: The `%notebook` doesn't quite seem to work. It seems like it is only saving recently executed code, rather than the entire notebook with all markdown cells, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It is easiest to select a destination before you create a program using Jupyter Notebook; as then you do not run into this issue.

However, since you have already made a program, one possible solution is to make a copy of the file, move it to your desired location, and then delete the old file. **Before doing this, ensure that you have saved it first, otherwise data might be lost.**