# Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL 2) and Jupyter Lab : Save a new Jupyter Notebook under the file system of Linux instead of Windows

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, filesystems, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jupyter-lab

I installed Jupyter Lab on WSL Ubuntu. I can lunch Jupyter Lab from Linux terminal,and it lunches from the Linux system as follows:

> [I 02:52:56.256 LabApp] JupyterLab beta preview extension loaded from 
>   /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyterlab 
>  [I
>   02:52:56.256 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is
>   /home/user/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab 
>  [I 02:52:56.273 LabApp] Serving
>   notebooks from local directory: /home/user/pythoncode 
>  [I 02:52:56.273 LabApp] 0
>   active kernels 
> [I 02:52:56.274 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running
>   at: 
>  [I 02:52:56.274 LabApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=8a6e...

This will open Jupyter Lab on Chrome browser from which I can start a new Jupyter Notebook with Python [conda env:root]*

However this new Jupyter Notebook will be automatically saved in 'C:\Users\user' under the Windows file system instead of the Linux file system. Although I was expecting that it will be saved under '/home/user/pythoncode' or 'home/user/anaconda3/share/jupyter/lab' in the Linux file system.

Even when I have a Jupyter notebook on the Linux file system, it gives an error when try to open it using 'Open from Path' as follows:

> Cannot open 
>   Could not find path: \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\user\pythoncode\mynotebook.ipynb

There are two questions:

(1) How to save this new Jupyter Notebook in a directory in the Linux file system? 
(2) How to access Linux file system from the File Browser of Jupyter Lab?

Comment: How to save this new Jupyter Notebook in a directory in the Linux file system? Using this magic command will save the notebook in the Linux file system. %notebook "\\wsl$/Ubuntu/home/user/pythoncode/filename.ipynb". Also,  the magic command %%writefile "\\wsl$/Ubuntu/home/user/pythoncode/filename.py" to save a file. More details can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41110338/how-to-save-a-file-into-a-directory-in-jupyter-notebook . But then how to open this file from the File Browser of Jupyter Lab or from anywhere in Jupyter Lab in general?

Comment: Were you able to get this solved? If not, see my answer for starting with your WSL2 IP to your similarly worded question https://stackoverflow.com/q/62353890/5369706

Flagging this for dupe, however, please let me know if that does the trick. I'm able to save notebooks just fine on the 'nix side of WSL2, that way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL 2) and Jupyter Lab : How to open a Jupyter Notebook saved at the Linux file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62353890/windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-2-and-jupyter-lab-how-to-open-a-jupyter-note)